# Add a back hyperlink in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

How can i hyperlink to the "previous shown slide" in PowerPoint (2016), like a back button in the web browser. Specifically, i have multiple slides which have hyperlinks on them to go to a particular Appendix slide. I want a hyperlink in that appendix slide to link bank to the referring slide (i.e., the last one that was shown).

Note: This will not be the the slide before it, and it will not be the same slide each time (i.e., since you can reach this appendix slide from several different slides in the power point).

Comment: Use a macro. [VBA PowerPoint - Go back to the slide I came from](//stackoverflow.com/a/12345006)

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill - that worked great, but as comment below, turns out it is also possible without the need for VBA using built in action buttons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a method to create a "back button" for your powerpoint slide to goto the previously viewed slid:

1. You will first create what you want the button to look like. Either insert an image or shape.
2. Once you have your shape / image selected, click on the Insert ribbon tab. Under the category "Links" you will find an "Action" button. Click that.
3. A dialog appears. Select the "Mouse Click" tab and then click on the "Hyperlink to" radio button. Select the drop down and pick "Last Slide Viewed". Click OK.

[image]

Note: The action can be selected to goto a particular slide, the last viewed one, the slide before the one selected, etc.. many options.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! (I find it weird that the option to go to last slide viewed slide only appears in the "action settings", but does not appear in the normal hyperlink options)

Comment: @kyrenia I actually didn't notice this either until I saw your question :)

Comment: Be aware, though, that Last Slide Viewed means *literally* that in PPT. If you're on slide 10 and click a link to slide 42, then click a Last Slide Viewed link, you'll go back to slide 10.  So far, so good.  But if there's a Last Slide Viewed link on slide 10, it'll take you back to 42, where the Last Slide Viewed link will take you back to slide 10.  It's a useful feature, but for one click only.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I agree you have to run your own logic to make it work